# How to use Sed to change letter to uppercase in first and second column in text file to upper case

Tags: sed

I have text file input.txt which has

```
april,december,month.gmail.com
lion,tiger,animal.gmail.com
```

Using `sed` change first and second columns to uppercase? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What is your expected output? Please include that explicitly in the question.
Also, what did you try before you asked? Please include that as well.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/^[a-z]*,[a-z]*,/\U&/' file
```

- `s`: substitute command
- `[a-z]*,`: search for zero ore more lowercase letter followed by a `,`. The pattern is repeated for second field
- the `\U` sequence turns the replacement to uppercase
- `\U` is applied to `&` which reference the matched string

or if there is only three comma separated fields:

```
sed 's/^[a-z].*,/\U&/' file
```

output:

```
APRIL,DECEMBER,month.gmail.com
LION,TIGER,animal.gmail.com
```

As @Sundeep suggests, the second sed can be shortened to:

```
s/^.*,/\U&/
```

which converts all characters until last `,` is found

For more on GNU sed substitution command, see [this article](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html)

Comment: the second sed can be shortened to `sed 's/^.*,/\U&/'`

Comment: @naresh I added some explanations in answer.